# "Incorrect syntax" when using a common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

```
WITH list_dedup (Company, duplicate_count) AS
(
     SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Email) AS 'RowNumber'
     FROM
         Travels
)
```

**Error**:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: I think the number (and types) of columns in the CTE must match what you select in the actual query.

Comment: You need to have a statement using the CTE after the definition. e.g. `WITH list_dedup (Company, duplicate_count) AS ( ... ) SELECT * FROM   list_dedup `

Answer (score 9):

You are missing a final select for the common table expression (**after** the definition of the CTE):

```
WITH list_dedup  (Company,duplicate_count) As
(
  select *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER by Email) As "RowNumber"
  From Travels
)
select *  
from list_dedup;
```

But this will not because the CTE is defined to have **two** columns (through the `WITH list_dedup  (Company,duplicate_count)`) but your select inside the CTE returns *at least* three columns (company, email, rownumber). You need to either adjust the column definition for the CTE, or leave it out completely:

```
WITH list_dedup As
(
  select *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER by Email) As "RowNumber"
  From Travels
)
select *  
from list_dedup;
```

---

The `As "RowNumber"` in the inner select also doesn't make sense when the column list is defined, because then the CTE definition defines the column names. Any alias used *inside* the CTE will not be visible outside of it (*if* the CTE columns are specified in the `with .. (...) as` part).

Answer (score 4):

You've just *set up* your CTE - now you need to **use it!**

```
WITH list_dedup (Company, duplicate_count) AS
(
     SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Email) AS 'RowNumber'
     FROM
         Travels
)
SELECT *
FROM list_dedup
```

Answer (score 0):

With marc_s's answer, you may also need a `;`

```
;WITH list_dedup (Company, duplicate_count) AS
(
     SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Email) AS 'RowNumber'
     FROM
         Travels
)

SELECT * FROM list_dedup
```